# Problem with validating ModelForm

Tags: python, django, forms, modelform

I use ModelForm to create my form. All works fine except 1 thing - validating the unique field.
Code:

```
class Article(models.Model):
...
title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, error_messages={'max_length' : 'max translation',
                                                                                                    'unique' : 'unique translation',
                                                                                                    'required' : 'req translation',})
...

class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
...
title = forms.CharField(max_length=255, min_length=3, error_messages={'required' : 'req translation',
                                                                                             'min_length' : 'min translation',
                                                                                             'max_length' : 'max translation',
                                                                                             'unique' : 'unique translation',})
```

But when I save my form with  non-unique title I don't get my custom translated error but I get default error. How to fix it, that my unique field error is displayed?

**EDIT:**
I found, I think, very convenient way to do that. Maybe someone will use it:)

```
def unique_error_message(self, model_class, unique_check):
    if 'put_field_name_here' in unique_check and len(unique_check) == 1:
        return 'Here goes a custom unique error'

    return super(Article, self).unique_error_message(model_class, unique_check)
```

Comment: Where did you see in the documentation that `unique` is a valid key for the `error_messages` dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

There's no `unique` key for customizing validation messages.  I'd say it's not worth it to customize, but if you must, following approach should help:

```
import re
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
       result = super(ArticleForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
       if self.non_field_errors:
           for i,msg in enumerate(self.non_field_errors):
               if re.match("^.+ already exists\.$", msg):
                   self.errors["__all__"][i] = custom_msg # Put your own text here
       return result
```

This solution relies on undocumented internals of Django, but it should do the trick for now.  Again, my recommendation is to stick with default.